# WPF Multiline TextBox : find and highlight the content in the textbox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

How to find and highlight the search result in the WPF multiline text box?

Answer (score 0):

```
textbox.SelectionStart = 0;
textbox.SelectionLength = textbox.Text.Length;
```